# Tomcat user auth-How to limit tomcat-user login attemps before getting HTTP/401?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, tomcat7

How to control on user auth' in tomcat7 for the following:

- Limit user login attemps, as example 5 times for a user?

  It looks that using the code below in server.xml it's done-at least according to the logs, but, the problem/question is that after exactly 3 failures anyway got HTTP error 401.

  (*I did failures for testing-there is no problem to login with the correct credentials*).
- What's the configuraion for login attemps before getting HTTP/401?

Configurations:

Tomcat 7.0.34, with simple JAVA Web-Application.

Added this in server.xml:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm"
  failureCount="5" lockOutTime="300" cacheSize="100" 
  cacheRemovalWarningTime="360"> 
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
      resourceName="UserDatabase" />
</Realm>
```

Added/allowed  in tomcat-users.xml

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Demo-Only-resource</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/DoSomething</url-pattern>            
        <url-pattern>/hideme.html</url-pattern>            
    </web-resource-collection>

    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>users</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>    
</security-constraint>

<security-role>
    <role-name>users</role-name>
</security-role>

<login-config>
     <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
     <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
     </form-login-config>
</login-config>    

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DoSomething</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.flrdemo.DoSomething</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DoSomething</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/DoSomething</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>DoSomething</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>   
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        15
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

- comment: code-all works except the option to control on login attemps (failures) before getting http error 401 Unauthorized error.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm" failureCount="10">` worked well for me.

In fact, failureCount value defaults to 5, that means you have to check your login configuration in another place.